# Can't get mongoose/mongoDB to throw a 11000 (Duplicate Error)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm sure to be missing something obvious here. My understanding was that the code below should throw an 11000 Duplicate Key Error, but it just adds both users to the database, and doesn't throw any errors. Anyone have any ideas how to make the email unique?  db version v2.4.5.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/db");

var User = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
    email: {type: String, index: true, unique: true}
}));

new User({
    email: "a@duplicate.com"
}).save(function(err,user){
    console.log(err);
});

new User({
    email: "a@duplicate.com"
}).save(function(err,user){
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Edit**

I seem to get it to work by going to the mongo command line, and typing:

```
db.users.ensureIndex({email:1},{unique:true});
```

The node script then works fine as expected and throws the errors. However, I am not sure why this isn't working through Mongoose. The output from mongoose debug is:

```
Mongoose: users.ensureIndex({ email: 1 }) { safe: undefined, background: true, unique: true }
Mongoose: users.insert({ __v: 0, _id: ObjectId("51fb961445cf690000000001"), email: 'a@duplicate.com' }) {}
Mongoose: users.insert({ __v: 0, _id: ObjectId("51fb961445cf690000000002"), email: 'a@duplicate.com' }) {}
Err=null
Err=null
```

I notice that ensureIndex line in the output fails if I execute it manually.

Comment: Turned out to be a number of factors. In the example above, if I left a 1 second gap between ensuring the index and adding the users, it would work as expected. The other part was to make sure the collection doesn't already have any duplicates in it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your index didn't stick, which you later fixed the syntax.

```
db.users.getIndexes()
```

Use that to verify that there are indexes on the collection next time.